# STLLoader.js code example for starting with three.js? Is there any good clean sample code?

Tags: javascript, three.js, stl

I have to include the STLLoader.js of three.js into my web application but can't find some good clean code examples on how to start.

On the https://threejs.org website there is only the example demonstration for the STLLoader (https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_stl) but I can't find some clean sample code for the STLLoader (except for this one: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_stl.html which is still quite difficult to understand for beginners), like there is for some other Loaders e.g. the OBJLoader (https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/loaders/OBJLoader)...

Please help me out with this:)

Comment: TBH, the example `webgl_loader_stl` should sufficiently demonstrate how you use the class in your code. What's unclear about that?

Comment: I now found the code you said, but there is so much stuff in it that it is very unclear which part of the code is essentially necessary and which isn't! For every other Loader there is a very clear documentation on the side, but not for STLLoaders:)

Comment: Sorry, but there is not much to document. Create an instance of `STLLoader`, call the `load()` by passing in the URL to your STL asset and an `onLoad()` callback handler. Then create a mesh with the resulting geometry and add it to the scene. Basically the same process like in all other loaders. BTW: It's not correct to say that there is a documentation for every other loader. In fact, most loaders don't have one.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not a professional yet. I thought it is more difficult than that! I have now figured it out by myself and it is working just fine. Sorry for bothering you! And with the other Loaders, you are right! I made a mistake. SRY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is what i came up with at the end...
For all those who had problems figuring it out too:)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>STLLoader Test</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="three.js-master/build/three.js"></script>
        <script src="three.js-master/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script src="three.js-master/examples/jsm/loaders/STLLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS (custom.js):

```
// Necessary for camera/plane rotation
var degree = Math.PI/180;

// Setup
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Resize after viewport-size-change
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
});

// Adding controls
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

// Ground (comment out line: "scene.add( plane );" if Ground is not needed...)
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(500, 500 ),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x999999, specular: 0x101010 } )
);
plane.rotation.x = -90 * degree;
plane.position.y = 0;
scene.add( plane );
plane.receiveShadow = true;

// ASCII file - STL Import
var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
loader.load( './stl/1.stl', function ( geometry ) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xFFFFFF, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 200 } );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.position.set( 0, 0, 0);
    scene.add( mesh );
} );

// Binary files - STL Import
loader.load( './stl/2.stl', function ( geometry ) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xFFFFFF, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 200 } );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.position.set( 0, 20, 0);
    scene.add( mesh );
} );

// Camera positioning
camera.position.z = 100;
camera.position.y = 100;
camera.rotation.x = -45 * degree;

// Ambient light (necessary for Phong/Lambert-materials, not for Basic)
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1);
scene.add(ambientLight);

// Draw scene
var render = function () {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

// Run game loop (render,repeat)
var GameLoop = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(GameLoop);

    render();
};

GameLoop();
```

And of course you need to download the [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/archive/master.zip) project and include it into your project root.

Leon

Comment: Nice work digging through things and trying them out until you got it to work. Thanks for sharing with the community.